# CreateAlias: Setting alias 'sitecore_custom_web_index_primary_alias' to collection 'sitecore_custom_web_index' failed

Tags: solr

I have configured a High Availability for SOLR solution with

- 2 x SOLR
- 3 x Zookeeper

While I was building the indexes everything went well, except for the following

> 7816 05:28:53 ERROR SwitchOnRebuildSolrSearchIndex: CreateAlias: Setting alias 'sitecore_custom_web_index_primary_alias' to collection 'sitecore_custom_web_index' failed. Response body: SolrNet.ResponseHearder

Unfortunately it does not log anything else.

Any ideas why this occur?

Comment: Anything is Solr logs?

Comment: Nothing about this particular core

Comment: Why 3x zookper and only 2x solrs? In case if one of two solr fails, your whole cloud will fail too.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the index rebuild process it will switch the 2 Aliases over the 2 collections. 
To put the rebuilt index live, and the old index under the rebuild alias.

Do your two collections exist in Solr? In particular "sitecore_custom_web_index".

If your collection doesn't exist it will error trying to set an Alias for it.

You can debug the commands getting sent to Solr, by running your iis app pool as your current user, changing the solr connection string from localhost:port to localhost.:port (notice the .) and running fiddler.

Or looking in the Solr logs.

Or construct it from documentation and your configuration.
https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-createalias

Once you know the Solr command, you can try calling Solr with that command to set the Alias yourself and see if works/fails.

Another note, the collection api only works in SolrCloud mode, you mention you have Zookeeper so should be fine. Check that in Solr you can see the Cloud left hand nav link, and the graph page shows a healthy green cluster.

Comment: I thought that index was missing but it is not, I have listed all alias - http://localhost:8993/solr/zookeeper?detail=true&path=/aliases.json - and it was there, then I checked all information from Solr Cores - http://localhost:8993/solr/admin/collections?action=CLUSTERSTATUS - and nothing missing.

Comment: what's your secondary collection called? what happens when you try to call the createalias command to the other collection the alias isn't currently set to. can you successfully switch back and forth via the solr command?

Comment: sitecore_custom_web_index_secondary_alias. I will check what happens if I try to create a new alias with same name. And not sure what do you mean about "switch back and forth via solr command"

Comment: thats the second alias, what about the second collection name? there are 2 collections and 2 aliases.